# Missing config/default directory error after patching the latest critical vulnerability

Tags: 8, security, upgrading

After hearing about the latest [Drupal Critical Security warning](https://www.drupal.org/psa-2019-02-19), I went ahead and updated the following packages in my `composer.json` file.

`drupal/core` from `8.5.8` to `8.5.11`

`drupal/jsonapi` from `1.7` to `1.25`

`drupal/metatag` from `1.4` to `1.8`

`drupal/paragraph` from `1.2` to `1.6`

The composer installation process went fine, but when I ran `drush updatedb` I started seeing this error in the output:

```
$ drush updatedb
The directory <em class="placeholder">/mnt/www/html/my_project/docroot/../config/default</em> does not exist.                   [error]
Requirements check reports errors. Do you wish to continue? (y/n): y
No database updates required
```

I've never had a `config/default` directory before so I don't know why it is complaining about it now. I also don't notice any adverse effects in my actual CMS, all the pages and forms seem to be working just as they did before the upgrade. When I run this `drush` command, I also don't notice any new errors/warnings in the logs.

**What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?**

Comment: Is your site on Acquia (even if you're running this locally)?

Comment: @Clive Yeah, my site is on Acquia. I get this error only on my Acquia machines, and not while running locally.